# How to fix rangeError during inserting item into AnimatedList (connected to Firebase database)

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-animatedlist

I'm inserting a document to a database and updating a GlobalKey's currentState of an AnimatedList in order to let it know about new item added
[i'm geetting rangeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mCHZ.png)

but after a few moments widget's rebuild fixes error screen and my new item add normally

I think the problem is that getting data from database have not enough time for updating cause when i'm using this:

```dart
sleep(const Duration(seconds:1));
```

the error doesn't appear

Also I was checking the number of items in list and number of documents of snapshot.data, they're not equal during the widget's build which give me an error, but they're equal during the rebuild, which starts just after the error's build
The same is about the removing, but there's no error screen during removing

Here's my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////LIST/////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class Item {
  Item({this.name, this.icon});
  Icon icon;
  String name;
}

class ListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListScreenState createState() => _ListScreenState();
}

class _ListScreenState extends State<ListScreen> {
  GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();
  int  id;
  bool isInit = true;
  var animatedList;

  _addItem() {
    Firestore.instance.collection('incrementID').document('IDINCREMENTATION')
        .setData({'lastID':--id});
    setState(() {
      Firestore.instance.collection('items').document('ITEM_$id')
          .setData({'name':'Item $id'});
      listKey.currentState.insertItem(0);

      //sleep(const Duration(seconds:1));
    });
  }

  _removeItem(int index, DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    setState(() {
      Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async{
        await transaction.delete(snapshot.reference);
      });
      listKey.currentState.removeItem(
        index,
            (context, animation) => buildItem(context, snapshot, 0, animation),
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      );
    });
  }

  Widget buildItem(
      BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document, int index, Animation<double> animation) {
    return SizeTransition(
      axis: Axis.vertical,
      sizeFactor: animation,
      child: SizedBox(
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(document['name']),
          onTap: (){
            _removeItem(index, document);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
// getting last used id
  getData() async {
    return await Firestore.instance.collection('incrementID').getDocuments();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      getData().then((val) {
        id = int.parse(val.documents[0].data['lastID'].toString());
      });
      return Scaffold(
        body: Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: Firestore.instance.collection('items').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData ) return const Text('Loading...');
                animatedList = new AnimatedList(
                  key: listKey,
                  initialItemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
                    return
                      buildItem(
                          context, snapshot.data.documents[index], index,
                          animation);
                  },
                );
                return animatedList;
              },
            )),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _addItem,
          tooltip: 'Decrement',
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably `await` and then `insertItem()`.

```
_addItem() async {
  await Firestore.instance.collection('incrementID').document('IDINCREMENTATION')
      .setData({'lastID':--id});
  await Firestore.instance.collection('items').document('ITEM_$id')
      .setData({'name':'Item $id'});

  setState(() {
    listKey.currentState.insertItem(0);
  });
}
```